# How to get a location header from GraphDB transaction API inside a Javascript application?

Tags: http, cors, graphdb

In order to get 'Location' header in the /transactions endpoint of GraphDB into a JavaScript App, the server needs to send the "Access-Control-Expose-Headers" header [1].

How to expose Location header in GraphDB for JavaScript requests?

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: RDF4J sends transaction ID through location header. I need this Id in order to use it for next API calls.

Comment: I am running graphdb as 

graphdb -Dgraphdb.workbench.cors.enable=true -p /tmp/graphdb.pid

In documentation, the default value for graphdb.workbench.cors.origin seems to be * by default.

Comment: OK, I was hoping that whoever wrote the CORS support in the graphdb sources was knowledgable enough about CORS to anticipate that using -Dgraphdb.workbench.cors.enable=true should also cause the value of the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header to be automatically set to what’s needed. But apparently not. So it seems the graphdb CORS support is deficient, and unless graphdb otherwise provides some way to set arbitrary response headers, you might be out of luck. Your only alternative would then be to put some kind of proxy between it and your frontend JavaScript code.

Answer (score 0):

This was accepted as a GraphDB bug and solved in GraphDB 9.3 - http://graphdb.ontotext.com/documentation/standard/release-notes.html.